# How to return multiple columns in moor aggregate advanced query

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-moor

How to return quantity and subtotal in the map for the dart query using moor flutter.

```
Stream<double> qtyOfItemOnRegister(String transactionNumber, int itemId,
  String uom, String transactionStatus) {
final quantity = db.salesOrderDetailTemp.quantity.sum();
final subtotal = db.salesOrderDetailTemp.subTotal.sum();
final query = selectOnly(db.salesOrderDetailTemp)
  ..addColumns([quantity, subtotal]);

return query.map((row) => row.read(quantity)).watchSingle();
```

}